# Silverlight mouse left button down issue

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, mouseevent, mouseleftbuttondown

In a Silverlight 3 project I am using mouse left button down event on a border control but found out that the event is raised even when I click the button slightly outside the border like 5-10 pixels.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Thanks in anticipation!

Following is the XAML in which we are capturing the event of brdSelect:

```
        <Border  MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_Mousedown" x:Name="brdSelect" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="#FF2D9FD2">
            <Grid x:Name="grdSelect" >

                <Border x:Name="brdImage"   BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="5" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                   <Image Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Stretch="UniformToFill" x:Name="imgMotive"/>
                </Border>

                <Image Height="Auto" Stretch="UniformToFill" x:Name="imgtmp" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <Image Height="13" Width="13" Source="../Images/rotate_small.JPG" Stretch="None" x:Name="imgRotate" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,0,2,0" Width="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Image Height="13" Width="13" Source="../Images/delete_small.JPG" Stretch="None" x:Name="imgDelete"  Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Image Source="../Images/resize_small.JPG" Stretch="None" x:Name="imgResize" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"  Grid.Column="2" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0"/>

    </Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtLabel" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-80,0,0,-20" Width="80" Text="X: 0 --- Y: 0" Foreground="Red" TextWrapping="Wrap" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

</Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't also have a margin applied, or content inside the border with negative margins?

Comment: Sharing your XAML might help.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the problem is in `MouseLeftButtonDown` event handling. In MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979694%28VS.95%29.aspx) I found:

> The MouseLeftButtonDown event is a
>   bubbling event. This means that if
>   multiple MouseLeftButtonDown events
>   are defined for a tree of elements,
>   **the event is received by each object
>   in the object hierarchy, starting with
>   the object that directly receives the
>   event, and then bubbles to each
>   successive parent element.** The
>   bubbling metaphor indicates that the
>   event starts at the bottom and works
>   its way up the object tree. For a
>   bubbling event, the sender parameter
>   identifies the object where the event
>   is handled, not necessarily the object
>   that actually received the input
>   condition that initiated the event.

You have a child border with `CornerRadius="5"`. May be this property actually causes child border to receive mouse event when visually this should not happen. Although this depends on actual implementation and you'd better check this.

Comment: I tried playing with brdImage and all other controls in hierarchy but didnt work. Any ideas what I should look for?